# Laplace Transformations fill in the blank

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

fill in the question mark

if $$\mathcal{L}{f(t)}(s)=\dfrac{s}{(\sqrt{s} +1)^3}$$ then Laplace $${e^{-2t} f(t)}=?$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts and can share what you have tried? Regards

Comment: the answer is (s+2)/[(sqrt(s+2)) +1]^3 i just dont know how

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the [*Time Shift Property*](http://www3.ul.ie/~mlc/support/Loughborough%20website/chap20/20_3.pdf).

The result is:

$$ \dfrac{s+2}{(\sqrt{s+2} +1)^3}$$

Comment: You've been busy today helping out! (My tally today had a lot of zeros!)

Comment: @amWhy: As you can see, I too have been a lot of those! :-( Thanks for the support!